# AppleScript: If a file does not exist

Tags: applescript

I need some way to determine if a particular file exists. If it exists do one script if not then do another script. Here was my logic in applescript:

```
If exists "File:Path:To:theFile"

tell application "Finder"
open "File:Path:To:the:script"
end tell

else

tell application "Finder"
open "File:Path:To:the:Anotherscript"
end tell

end if
```

The only problem is that sometimes when i use the above logic the script fails saying can't find the file. I need a full proof, never fails way to see if a file exists. I'm open to using the terminal, or applescript. I'm sure someone has run into this before but I have looked all over the web for an answer but could not find one.

Answer (score 8):

In your original code you're giving the exists function a string, rather than a file, even though it's the path to a file. You have to explicitly give it a file, or it treats it the same as if you had tried to do

```
exists "god"
```

or

```
exists "tooth fairy"
```

The exists command won't know what you're talking about. You could use

```
return exists alias "the:path:to:a:file"
```

but aliases don't work unless the file actually exists, so a non-existent file will create an error. You could of course catch the error and do something with it, but it's simpler to just give the exists function a file object. File objects belong to the Finder application, so:

```
return exists file "the:path:to:a:file" of application "Finder"
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following to see if an item in the Finder exists:

```
on FinderItemExists(thePath)
    try
        set thePath to thePath as alias
    on error
        return false
    end try
    return true
end FinderItemExists
```

I think what you're missing is conversion of the path to an alias.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good place for a [`try`...`on error` block](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/applescript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-128973). I believe the following should do what you want:

```
tell application "Finder"
   try
      open "File:Path:To:the:script"
   on error
      open "File:Path:To:the:Anotherscript"
   end try
end tell
```